# Laravel / Eloquent model relation viewer

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1, relationship

So I was wondering if there were any packages I could use with Laravel 5 to show me visually my model relations? I know I could possibly do this using an SQL relation GUI but I was curious about a Laravel one?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use `dd(Model::with(['relation1', 'relation2'])->get())` which is an easy way to check relationship.

Comment: Cool, I will give that a try

Comment: To be clear, you're asking for something that produces something like an ERD that shows you the logical relations, not something that allows you to actually CRUD real physical instances of models and related models, right?

Comment: Yes exactly :) I have found the answer but if you know of anything else it would be cool to see it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Laravel Schema Designer is an online application helping designing Laravel relation database visually.

It is also possible to export migration code, schema, model, controller, form or more to Laravel as code.

It is as said an online FREE tool/service and I find it useful.

Laravel Shcema Designer link: http://laravelsd.com

View an random example http://laravelsd.com/share/V3JXF4.

Comment: Hey, this is awesome. I will be using that :) thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Laravel SchemaSpy](https://github.com/Stolz/laravel-schema-spy).

With SchemaSpy you can analyze the schema metadata of a database and generate browser readable files with useful information such:

- Visual ER diagram.
- Proper table insertion/deletion order for database
  migrations.

Α drawback of SchemaSpy is that you need to have java installed on your server in order to work.

Comment: Thanks, it looks pretty much exactly what I need.

Comment: I am happy to hear that.

Answer (score 2):

If you still have this issue, you can try our modeling tool Skipper  (https://www.skipper18.com) with new Laravel support. During the beta phase, it is completely free.

It does exactly what you search and also much more:

- import existing project from a database and get its diagram
- In user-friendly interface maintain the project via the graphical model
- while editing it's possible to continuously export up-dated model objects and migrations files
- projects can be saved for late, multiple projects can share modules

[image: Example of ORM Designer model]

If you want to try it, you can download it here https://www.skipper18.com/en/download, and in the initial application license screen select "Laravel Beta license".

Answer (score 0):

The [Laravel Administrator](https://github.com/FrozenNode/Laravel-Administrator) package:

> Administrator is an administrative interface builder for Laravel. With Administrator you can visually manage your Eloquent models and their relations, and also create stand-alone settings pages for storing site data and performing site tasks.

PS: I haven't tried it. I just saw it on a question yesterday.

Comment: Thanks, it looks good I accepted the other one as it's a little more what I was after. Sorry but I couldn't give you both the bounty :(

Comment: The link appears to be broken and now redirects to malware. It seems the author isn't keeping his site up to date. The project is still located on github, last updated Jun 16' - https://github.com/FrozenNode/Laravel-Administrator

It seems someone made a mirror of the documentation site here: frozennode.mediaceh.ru